# Number(id) or +id result in different values depending on the input value

Tags: javascript, typescript2.4

```
id: number;

this.id = +id;

When local id is null then +id results in 0
When local id is undfined then +id results in NaN
```

The same results I get with `Number(id)` instead of the `+id`

How can I get consistent/same return value for the **not successful conversion** into a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both `0`, `null`, `NaN` and `undefined` are falsy, you could just set the value to something if it's falsy

```
this.id = (+id) || 0;
```

```js
console.log( (+0) || 0 )           // 0
console.log( (+null) || 0 )        // 0
console.log( (+undefined) || 0 )   // 0
```

Comment: I replaced || 0 with || null as I wanted to only test for that value! :-) Thanks!